# Сделать размер игры 1000 на 440

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы эта игра работала корректно при размере  1000 на 440(сейчас её размер 1600 на 440)

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: сейчас размер этой игры 1600 на 440 мне нужно чтобы размер этой игры был 1000 на 440.

Comment: Если проблема в наличии у тебя такого желания, то вопрос не по теме stackoverflow. А если ты пытался решить данную задачу, и столкнулся с конкретными трудностями - то опиши их: "выполняю такие-то действия, ожидая такой-то результат, но вместо него получаю вот такое".

Comment: 2 числа в конце скрипта не меняли?

Comment: Пытался поменять вот эти параметры canvas.width = 1600;// тут сделал 1000 ,но лук пропал как сделать чтобы делал 1000 ,но игра продолжала корректно работать canvas.height = 440;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

изменение в двух местах `position: new Vector(900,220),` и `canvas.width = 1000;` делает игру размером 1000 на 440

Просто пробуйте немного разобратся в коде

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("archery"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  targetObject,
  bowObject,
  pointsTally = 0;

function addPoints(points) {
  pointsTally += points;
  var pointsEl = document.getElementById('points');
  pointsEl.innerHTML = pointsTally + ' points';;
}

var Controller = {
  objects: [],
  render: function() {
    Controller.clearCanvas();
    var i = 0,
      l = Controller.objects.length,
      object;
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      object = Controller.objects[i];
      object.update();
      object.render();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(Controller.render);
  },
  clearCanvas: function() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
  }
}

var BaseObject = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = {
    position: new Vector(60, 200),
    angle: 0,
    scale: new Vector(1, 1),
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    update: function() {

    },
    render: function() {
      ctx.save();
      this.applyTransformations();
      this.draw();
      ctx.restore();
    },
    applyTransformations: function() {
      ctx.translate(+this.position.x, +this.position.y);
      ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.scale(this.scale.x, this.scale.y);
      ctx.translate(-this.position.x, -this.position.y);

    },
    draw: function() {
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + -this.width / 2, this.position.y + -this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }

  var obj = Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
  Controller.objects.push(obj);
  return obj;
}

var Arrow = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    height: 8,
    speed: 24,
    angle: -20,
    gravity: 16,
    flying: false,
    dead: false,
    width: 80,
    direction: 1,
    update: function() {
      if (this.flying) {
        this.applyMotion();
        if (this.position.y > 1000 || (targetObject && this.position.x + this.width / 2 >= targetObject.position.x)) {
          this.position.x = targetObject.position.x - this.width / 2 + Math.random() * 20;
          var distanceFromCentre = Math.abs((this.position.y + Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180) * 1.1 * this.width / 2 - targetObject.position.y) / 100);
          distanceFromCentre *= 1 / (targetObject.height / 100);
          distanceFromCentre *= 5;     
          distanceFromCentre = Math.floor(distanceFromCentre);
          distanceFromCentre *= 2;
          var points = 10 - distanceFromCentre;
          if (points < 0)
            points = 0;
          addPoints(points);
          console.log(points, distanceFromCentre);
          this.flying = false;
          this.dead = true;
        }
      } else if (!this.dead) {
        if (this.direction > 0) {
          this.angle++;
          if (this.angle > 45)
            this.direction = -1;
        } else if (this.direction < 0) {
          this.angle--;
          if (this.angle < -45)
            this.direction = 1;
        }
        bowObject.angle = this.angle;
      }
    },
    applyMotion: function() {
      this.angle++;
      var xMotion = Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI / 180),
        yMotion = Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);
      this.position.x += this.speed * (xMotion > 0 ? xMotion : 0);
      this.position.y += yMotion > -1 && yMotion < 1 ? yMotion * this.gravity : 0;
    },
    draw: function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x - this.width / 2, this.position.y - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#4e342e';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + -this.width / 2, this.position.y - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height / 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#795548';
      ctx.fill();
      if (!this.dead) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2, this.position.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2, this.position.y - this.height);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2 + this.height * 2, this.position.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#9e9e9e';
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2, this.position.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2, this.position.y + this.height);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width / 2 + this.height * 2, this.position.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#757575';
        ctx.fill();
      }

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - this.width / 2 + this.height * 3, this.position.y + this.height / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 1.75 + this.height * 3, this.position.y + this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 1.75, this.position.y + this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 2, this.position.y + this.height / 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#283593';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - this.width / 2 + this.height * 3, this.position.y - this.height / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 1.75 + this.height * 3, this.position.y - this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 1.75, this.position.y - this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width / 2, this.position.y - this.height / 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#3f51b5';
      ctx.fill();
    }
  });

  var obj = Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
  return obj;
}

var Vector = function(x, y) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

var Target = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    position: new Vector(900, 220),
    height: 150,
    scale: new Vector(0.5, 1),
    draw: function() {

      ctx.rect(this.position.x - 50, 0, 350, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#5d4037';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 200, 0, 100, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#3e2723';
      ctx.fill();


      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - 200, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - 300, this.position.y / 3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 100, this.position.y / 4);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y / 3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, 0);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#388e3c';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - 300, this.position.y / 3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 100, this.position.y / 4);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y / 3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y / 10);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#212121';
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + 40, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#bf360c";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.125;
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + 40, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height * 0.8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#424242";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();

      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height * 0.6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#42a5f5";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height * 0.4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#f44336";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height * 0.2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#ffca28";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.125;
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
    }
  });

  return Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
}
targetObject = new Target();

var Bow = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    position: new Vector(60, 200),
    angle: 0,
    scale: new Vector(3, 1),
    draw: function() {

      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x - 185, this.position.y, 200, Math.PI * 1.9, Math.PI * 0.1);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x - 187, this.position.y, 200, Math.PI * 1.9, Math.PI * 0.1);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y + 63, 5, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y - 78, 5, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y + 63, 1, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y - 78, 1, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + 5, this.position.y - 78);
      var arrowPosX = this.arrow.position.x - this.arrow.width / (2 * this.scale.x);

      ctx.lineTo((arrowPosX < this.position.x + 5 ? arrowPosX : this.position.x + 5), (arrowPosX < this.position.x + 5 ? this.arrow.position.y : this.position.y));
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 5, this.position.y + 78);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.stroke();

    }
  });

  return Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
}

bowObject = new Bow();
//obj.render()

var obj = new Arrow({});
bowObject.arrow = obj;
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!obj.flying) {
    obj.flying = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      obj = new Arrow({
        angle: bowObject.angle
      });
      bowObject.arrow = obj;
    }, 200);
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(Controller.render);

/*window.addEventListener('resize', calculateCanvasWidth);

function calculateCanvasWidth() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
calculateCanvasWidth();*/

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 440;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background-color: #42a5f5;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="archery"></canvas>
<p id="points">0 points</p>
```

Comment: не заметил Ваш ответ пока писал то же самое =)

Answer (score 3):

Код написан достаточно неплохо, с точки зрения корректности, и изменение 2х параметров не повлияло на логику игры:

теперь ширина `1000` а позиция цели по `x` `900`

однако копи-пасты тут хоть отбавляй и с этим надо бы что-то сделать...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("archery"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    targetObject,
    bowObject,
    pointsTally = 0;

function addPoints(points) {
  pointsTally += points;
  var pointsEl = document.getElementById('points');
  pointsEl.innerHTML = pointsTally + ' points';;
}

var Controller = {
  objects : [],
  render: function() {
    Controller.clearCanvas();
    var i = 0,
        l = Controller.objects.length,
        object;
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      object = Controller.objects[i];
      object.update();
      object.render();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(Controller.render);
  },
  clearCanvas: function() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
  }
}

var BaseObject = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = {
    position: new Vector(60,200),
    angle: 0,
    scale: new Vector(1,1),
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    update : function() {
      
    },
    render : function() {
      ctx.save();
      this.applyTransformations();
      this.draw();
      ctx.restore();
    },
    applyTransformations : function() {
      ctx.translate(+this.position.x, +this.position.y);
      ctx.rotate(this.angle*Math.PI/180);
      ctx.scale(this.scale.x, this.scale.y);
      ctx.translate(-this.position.x, -this.position.y);
      
    },
    draw : function() {
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + -this.width/2, this.position.y + -this.height/2, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  
  var obj =  Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
  Controller.objects.push(obj);
  return obj;
}

var Arrow = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    height: 8,
    speed: 24,
    angle: -20,
    gravity : 16,
    flying: false,
    dead : false,
    width: 80,
    direction:1,
    update : function() {
      if (this.flying) {
        this.applyMotion();
        if (this.position.y > 1000 || (targetObject && this.position.x + this.width/2 >= targetObject.position.x)){
          this.position.x = targetObject.position.x - this.width/2 + Math.random() * 20;
          var distanceFromCentre = Math.abs((this.position.y + Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/180) * 1.1 * this.width/2 - targetObject.position.y)/100);
          distanceFromCentre *= 1/(targetObject.height/100);
          distanceFromCentre *= 5;
          distanceFromCentre = Math.floor(distanceFromCentre);
          distanceFromCentre *= 2;
          var points = 10 - distanceFromCentre;
          if (points < 0)
            points = 0;
          addPoints(points);
          console.log(points, distanceFromCentre);
          this.flying = false;
          this.dead = true;
        }
      } else if(!this.dead) {
        if (this.direction > 0) {
          this.angle ++;
          if (this.angle > 45)
            this.direction = -1;
        } else if (this.direction < 0) {
          this.angle --;
          if (this.angle < -45)
            this.direction = 1;
        }
        bowObject.angle = this.angle;
      }
    },
    applyMotion : function() {
      this.angle++;
      var xMotion =  Math.cos(this.angle * Math.PI/180),
          yMotion = Math.sin(this.angle * Math.PI/180);
        this.position.x += this.speed * (xMotion > 0 ? xMotion : 0);
        this.position.y += yMotion > -1 && yMotion < 1 ? yMotion * this.gravity : 0;
    },
    draw : function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x -this.width/2, this.position.y -this.height/2, this.width, this.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#4e342e';
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + -this.width/2, this.position.y-this.height/2, this.width, this.height/2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#795548';
      ctx.fill();
      if (!this.dead) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.width/2, this.position.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width/2, this.position.y - this.height);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width/2 + this.height*2, this.position.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#9e9e9e';
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.position.x + this.width/2, this.position.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width/2, this.position.y + this.height);
        ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + this.width/2 + this.height*2, this.position.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#757575';
        ctx.fill();
      }
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - this.width/2 + this.height*3, this.position.y + this.height/2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/1.75 + this.height*3, this.position.y + this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/1.75, this.position.y + this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/2, this.position.y + this.height/2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#283593';
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - this.width/2 + this.height*3, this.position.y - this.height/2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/1.75 + this.height*3, this.position.y - this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/1.75, this.position.y - this.height);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - this.width/2, this.position.y - this.height/2);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#3f51b5';
      ctx.fill();
    }
  });
  
  var obj = Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
  return obj;
}
  
var Vector = function(x, y) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
}

var Target = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    position: new Vector(900,220),
    height: 150,
    scale: new Vector(0.5,1),
    draw : function()  {
      
      ctx.rect(this.position.x - 50, 0, 350, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#5d4037';
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 200, 0, 100, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#3e2723';
      ctx.fill(); 
      
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - 200, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x - 300, this.position.y/3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 100, this.position.y/4);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y/3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, 0);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#388e3c';
      ctx.fill(); 
      
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x - 300, this.position.y/3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 100, this.position.y/4);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y/3);
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x + 500, this.position.y/10);
      ctx.fillStyle = '#212121';
      ctx.fill(); 
     
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + 40, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#bf360c";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.125;
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + 40, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
           
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height*0.8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#424242";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height*0.6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#42a5f5";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height*0.4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#f44336";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height*0.2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#ffca28";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.125;
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, Math.PI*0.5, Math.PI*1.5);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.height, 0, Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.fill();
    }
  });
  
  return Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
}
targetObject = new Target();

var Bow = function(opts) {
  var defaultOpts = new BaseObject({
    position: new Vector(60,200),
    angle: 0,
    scale: new Vector(3,1),
    draw : function()  {
      
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x -185, this.position.y, 200, Math.PI*1.9, Math.PI*0.1);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x -187, this.position.y, 200, Math.PI*1.9, Math.PI*0.1);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.stroke();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y + 63, 5, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y - 78, 5, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#37474f";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y + 63, 1, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(this.position.x + 2, this.position.y - 78, 1, 15);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#546e7a";
      ctx.fill();
      
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.position.x+5, this.position.y - 78);
      var arrowPosX = this.arrow.position.x - this.arrow.width/(2*this.scale.x);
      
      ctx.lineTo((arrowPosX < this.position.x + 5 ? arrowPosX : this.position.x + 5), (arrowPosX < this.position.x + 5 ? this.arrow.position.y : this.position.y));
      ctx.lineTo(this.position.x+5, this.position.y + 78);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#212121";
      ctx.stroke();    
      
    }
  });
  
  return Object.assign(defaultOpts, opts);
}

bowObject = new Bow();
//obj.render()

var obj = new Arrow({});
bowObject.arrow = obj;
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!obj.flying) {
    obj.flying = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      obj = new Arrow({angle: bowObject.angle});
      bowObject.arrow = obj; 
    }, 200);
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(Controller.render);

/*window.addEventListener('resize', calculateCanvasWidth);

function calculateCanvasWidth() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
calculateCanvasWidth();*/

canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 440;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  background-color: #42a5f5;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="archery"></canvas>
<p id="points">0 points</p>
```